# How can I create a mesh using the GDNative Godot api?

Tags: rust, godot, gdnative

I want to create a mesh using the godot-rust API. I'm confused why calling `Mesh::new()` doesn't work but `SurfaceTool::new()` does.
This is the error:

```
the trait bound `Mesh: Instanciable` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `Instanciable`:
  AESContext
  ARVRAnchor
  ARVRCamera
  ARVRController
  ARVRInterfaceGDNative
  ARVROrigin
  ARVRPositionalTracker
  AStar
and 531 others
```

I'm not sure what that means, but I think it's something like `Mesh` doesn't implement the `Instanciable` trait.
Here's the relevant code:

```rust
use gdnative::{prelude::*, api::{StaticBody, Mesh, SurfaceTool}};

fn init(handle: InitHandle) {
    handle.add_class::<Chunk>();
}
godot_init!(init);

struct Block;

#[derive(NativeClass)]
#[inherit(StaticBody)]
pub struct Chunk {
    blocks: Vec<Block>,
    st: Ref<SurfaceTool, Unique>,
    mesh: Option<Ref<Mesh, Unique>>,
    mesh_instance: Option<Ref<Mesh, Unique>>
}

impl Chunk {
    fn new(_base: &StaticBody) -> Self {
        let blocks = Vec::new();
        let st = SurfaceTool::new();
        let mesh = None;
        let mesh_instance = None;

        Chunk {
            blocks,
            st,
            mesh,
            mesh_instance
        }
    }

    fn update(&mut self) {
        match &self.mesh_instance {
            Some(instance) => {
                unsafe {
                    instance.call_deferred("queue_free", &[]);
                }
                self.mesh_instance = None;
            }

            None => {}
        }

        self.mesh = Some(Mesh::new());
    }
}

#[methods]
impl Chunk {
    #[method]
    fn _ready(&self, #[base] base: &StaticBody) {
        godot_print!("Hello World from StaticBody {}!", base.to_string());
    }
}
```

The error occurs on the `self.mesh = Some(Mesh::new())` line.

Comment: In my experience, using `SurfaceTool` from Rust is extremely slow, but this could have been due to [a threading issue](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/56524). A faster workaround is to create a `Vec<Vec3>` for the vertices (and similar for normals etc.), convert these using `Vector3Array::from_vec`, then set these directly using `ArrayMesh::add_surface_from_arrays`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create an object of the class `Mesh` directly. It is an abstract base class.

Instead create an `ArrayMesh` (`ArrayMesh` extends `Mesh`). The `ArrayMesh` is a mesh created form an array of vertex. And that is what `SurfaceTool` needs to work with. You should be able to confirm that the [`commit`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_surfacetool.html#class-surfacetool-method-commit) method of `SurfaceTool` wants an `ArrayMesh`.

The other class that extends `Mesh` that is available is `PrimitiveMesh`. Which you should not use directly either, because `PrimitiveMesh` is the base for the built-in meshes: `CapsuleMesh`, `CubeMesh`, `CylinderMesh`, `PlaneMesh`, `PrismMesh`, `QuadMesh`, and `SphereMesh`.